# Running syntax copied from Jamovi output in R console error

Tags: r, syntax, jamovi

Am new to Jamovi and exploring it. A cool feature is to be able to set Jamovi out put to syntax mode and copy paste that syntax from Jamovi to run in an R console.

After successfully drawing a bar plot in Jamovi, when I copy paste the syntax to run in R, the text part of the output appears fine but the bar plot fails to appear. Instead I get the following error:

> Error in str2lang(x) : :2:0: unexpected end of input 1:  ~     ^

The syntax pasted from Jamovi is:

```
 jmv::contTables(formula = ~ p5_edu:school_type, 
      data = PT, 
      barplot = TRUE)
```

If I change the syntax to suppress the bar-plot there is no error in the R console.

```
    jmv::contTables(formula = ~ p5_edu:school_type, 
                    data = PT, 
                    barplot = FALSE)
```

Am I missing something in the syntax. Any clues or fixes from anyone?

Versions in use:
Jamovi 2.4.2.0
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)